# Conditions to sabbatical holiday in France

Tags: france, workplace

I was interrested in sabbatical holiday in my country (France), and I would like to make sure that I understand correctly the official conditions.

Quoting [this (in the `condition` dropdown)](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2381#:%7E:text=Le%20cong%C3%A9%20sabbatique%20est%20un,minimale%20et%20une%20dur%C3%A9e%20maximale.):

> Le salarié doit avoir une ancienneté d'au moins 36 mois dans
> l'entreprise.

> The employee must have seniority of at least 36 months in the company.

And:

> Le salarié doit avoir effectué 6 années d'activité professionnelle.

> The employee must have completed 6 years of professional activity.

It seems pretty clear, but I just want to make sure that I need to match both of the following conditions:

- I need to have worked (at total in my life) at least 6 years **AND**
- I need to have worked at least 3 years (36 months) in the company I would ask a sabbatical from.

Is the above right ?

Comment: Can you please translate the quotes?

Comment: Sure thing ! It's done @DaleM